# how to plot max and min value in seaborn scatterplot?

Tags: python, seaborn

```
    import seaborn as sns
    df = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
    sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="island", y="body_mass_g",hue="sex",s=300)
```

I am using seaborn to plot scatter, I also want to plot x_max, x_min, y_min and y_max but i don't know how to do that, I can plot x_max,y_max and x_min,y_min but don't know how to do all 4. Any help will be great

Comment: Side note, but have you considered `stripplot` (without `s=300`) to better visualize the data with a jitter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd
    import seaborn as sns
    df = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
    var1="bill_depth_mm"
    var2="bill_length_mm"
    sns.scatterplot(x=var1,y=var2,data=df,color="blue")
    z=df[var1].max()
    df2=df[df[var1] == z] 
    sns.scatterplot(x=var1,y=var2,data=df2,color="green")
    print(df2[var1],df2[var1])
    
    z=df[var2].max()
    df2=df[df[var2] == z] 
    sns.scatterplot(x=var1,y=var2,data=df2,color="green")
    print(df2[var1],df2[var1])
    
    
    
    z=df[var1].min()
    df2=df[df[var1] == z] 
    sns.scatterplot(x=var1,y=var2,data=df2,color="red")
    print(df2[var1],df2[var1])
    
    z=df[var2].min()
    df2=df[df[var2] == z] 
    sns.scatterplot(x=var1,y=var2,data=df2,color="red")
    print(df2[var1],df2[var1])
```

Comment: Maybe add some explanation of your solution, to help future users ;)